# Anyway to save an background image so when it reloads it save your choice

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am developing a site where you can set a "dark mode" but when I access it or refresh it always sets it back to the light version. Is their anyway that choice can be set / saved on a device.

```
 <button onclick="document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#2e2e2e'">Dark Mode</button>
  <button onclick="document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white'">Light Mode</button>
```

This is all I got for now, Until I can figure out how to save that choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JavaScript Cookie

All code here

Note: I am using a Cookie that's name is: bodyColor;

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Testing Page</title>
</head>
<body onload="setbodycolor()">
<p>Testing Page</p>

<button onclick="setbodyBGDarkColor();setCookieDark()">Dark Mode</button>
<button onclick="setbodyBGWhileColor();setCookieWhite()">Light Mode</button>


<script>
    function setbodyBGDarkColor(){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#2e2e2e'
    }
    function setbodyBGWhileColor(){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white'
    }

    function setCookieDark(){
        document.cookie="bodyColor=#2e2e2e;expires=Wed, 18 Dec 2023 12:00:00 GMT"
    }
    function setCookieWhite(){
        document.cookie="bodyColor=#ffffff;expires=Wed, 18 Dec 2023 12:00:00 GMT"
    }


    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
        }
        return "";
    }

    function setbodycolor(){
        var bodyc=getCookie("bodyColor");
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = ""+bodyc;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I think it's better solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found this one on Vanilla JS. You can save your session.

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = sessionStorage.getItem('bg');
document.body.style.color = sessionStorage.getItem('cc');
function darker() {

 if ( sessionStorage.getItem('bg') === 'rgb(255, 255, 255)') {

        sessionStorage.setItem('bg', 'rgb(6, 23, 37)');

        sessionStorage.setItem('cc', '#777');

         }
        else if (sessionStorage.getItem('bg') == null || undefined) {
            sessionStorage.setItem('bg', 'rgb(6, 23, 37)');
            sessionStorage.setItem('cc', '#777');

        }
        else if( sessionStorage.getItem('bg') === 'rgb(6, 23, 37)') {

            sessionStorage.setItem('bg', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');
            sessionStorage.setItem('cc', '#333');


        }

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = sessionStorage.getItem('bg');
    document.body.style.color = sessionStorage.getItem('cc');

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways this can be done - one way would be to use the [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) API to achieve this as shown below:

```js
/* 
Local helper applies color to document background and saves that color for
recall on future page loads
*/
function applyTheme(color) {

  localStorage.set("themeColor", color);

  document.body.style.backgroundColor = themeColor;
}

/* 
Setup event hander that is called when DOM is ready
*/
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    /* 
    When DOM ready, load previous theme color and apply it (or default to 
    white if no color previously saved)
    */
    applyTheme(localStorage.get("themeColor") || "white");

    /* 
    Bind click event to buttons and invoke apply theme helper function
    */
    document.getElementById("dark").addEventListener("click", () => applyTheme("#2e2e2e"));        
    document.getElementById("light").addEventListener("click", () => applyTheme("white"));    
});
```

```html
<button id="dark">Dark Mode</button>
<button id="light">Light Mode</button>
```